# How to do a script that could output my 3d files with the required color/lighting and angle versions

Tags: python

I need to create versions of a large amount of 3d files in many different colors and  with varying degrees of tilt. Is it possible to create a script that could output my 3d files with the required color/lighting and angle versions. I am coming at this from an automation stand point. For instance in Photoshop there is a feature that lets you batch automate files from a folder.

Answer (score 1):

A great amount of automation is possible in Blender via Python scripting. Mostly any repetitive tasks can be automated and since it is scripting it is even more flexible and powerful than Photoshop's actions or batch processing scripts.

You can find more information on Blender's Python API in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/).

Be aware that the subject is quite complex and requires a lot of effort to master, so no single answer here on Blender Stack Exchange or other forums on the web will teach you to use this, however if you ask specific clear, well formed questions about specific issues you face while learning, Blender Stack Exchange can be a lot of help. You should attempt to use correct terminology, be specific and make the titles of your questions informative and reflecting the actual question. Best to form them as a question as well. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

When learning Blender's Python API, you can get a lot by studying the script examples that come with Blender:

[image]

As well as any add-ons that you can find in `[Blender's install directory]\[version number]\scripts\addons\`.

Blender's Python Console has a priceless autocomplete function as well, that shows you possible options when you start typing something if you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>(previously <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) while still hovering the mouse over the area of Python Console:

[image]

Oh, and I almost forgot - you need to know how to use Python obviously. You can find all about it at not a very surprising web address: [www.python.org](https://www.python.org). The website is amazing and really has everything you might need. This is also ridiculously good: [www.w3schools.com/python/](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) .

Comment: I understand it is a vauge type question. I guess I am looking for someone who could assist my company with this 3d type problem. A person with these type of skills, is there a good title for this kind of professional?

Comment: I don't think BSE is a very good place for job offers... I suppose you can find a lot of people who are able to help you, but I have no idea how it would be appropriate for you to go about it here - I don't see a lot of that happening around here. You could try Blenderartists.org forums. There is  a paid work section there: https://blenderartists.org/c/jobs/paid-work

Comment: See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/blender-paid-work/2400#2400 so job offers seem to be mostly considered as off-topic: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6

Comment: thank you for the information.