# How to create an exporter describing certain actions? + and make it as add on?

Tags: python, add-on

I just started looking at python with zero background of coding as I really need to create a custom exporter but it seems to far for me yet.

Anyone can guide me to create a py script which excutes the steps please?

1. placing selected objects to 0-0-0 world space, reset rotaion to 0-0-0, and scale 1
2. Apply modifier if selected objects have any.
3. Export the selected objects separately per object as objectname.fbx with selected operator Preset to the destination folder user selected.
4. return the objects back to the original transform, with original status.

furthermore I'd like to make it as an add-on with showing the default exporting window (showing the oprator settings, and the export location) so that I can easily find it this under - Export menu.

I would be more than happy with any input from you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [Python](https://www.python.org/doc/), [Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html), Templates menu in the Text Editor in Blender, also Blender's add-ons folder (usually `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\addons\` ). [Also see Autocomplete function in Python Console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/145660/60759) it helps a lot when learning Blender's Python API.

Comment: In addition to Martynas Žiemys' very good advice, there are many YouTube tutorials on creating addons. Do a search for what operation you are trying to do. It is quite likely someone has made a tutorial for it or some similar operation.